# unexpected behavior while loading the image from res/drawable folder

Tags: android

I am using the below code to load an image from res/drawable folder.
**But , sometimes it is loading correctly and in few other times it is loading a blank image.** What might the reason for that?

```
bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.p1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the reason because since API 22 **getResources().getDrawable()** is `deprecated`, so we can use following solution.

```
Drawable vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo, null);
Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
```

Comment: please check your drawable image's size. Sometimes size also arise the issue to not load. Just try to use default ic_launcher for testing.

Comment: I have moved the code to oncreate and working fine.Adding to this>I am using the mentioned code to get 9 (bird1 to bird9) images from drawable folder by manually giving each name.

How can i use an array or replace R.drawable.bird1 with variable ( as the below statement accept only actual value)to get all the 9 images in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way
`getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dog)).getBitmap();`
and if needed try casting it to BitmapDrawable
`((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dog)).getBitmap();`